# Bootstrap problems when I save the HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched for this and tried a few different keywords. I'm trying to learn and use Boostrap. I thought I had a good grasp on it a few months back. But now I have a problem with just the stock files working. I want to work with Jumbotron and the static Navbar. After I save the static navbar file and it's CSS and change it's locations, the drop down menu doesn’t work...

The only two things I did to the code is change the CSS locations for the navbar.css and bootstrap.min.css. When I try it in Chrome, FF & Safari, I get nothing and the # appears next to .html# in the address bar.

What am I missing. I'm sorry this is probably super easy, but I cant see it. Thank you for any help :)

literally I change two things from the code from here - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/ and save the css from navbar-static-top.css

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: try using chrome's developer mode, it will tell you if there are any js errors, and if any referenced files cannot be found

Comment: Deleted my answer as it didn't work, glad you managed to fix it (Y)

Answer (score 1):

It's OK, dumb problem solved. I forgot that Boostraps adds the JS at the bottom and I forgot to change the dir for the bootstrap.min.js file. All working and proper now :)